# Need webform with list of items, price, and total

Tags: webforms

Not sure that webform can do this, BUT my client sells yachts. They want a webform on the site that lists all of the boat options (a check-list) a potential customer might like to have and creates a subtotal at the bottom of the list as the customer checks items on the list.

The way it works: A visitor is interested in buying a boat so they go through the list and check(box) the item/s they want, and as they check the items a subtotal is calculated at the bottom of the list. Then the webform is submitted to the company sales to someone that will contact the potential customer to continue the sales effort.

This should be something like a spreadsheet, but the list cannot be changed (only the checkbox next to each item). The subtotal is affected only by the items on the list that are checked.

This might better be done by something like ubercart, but seems ubercart would be overkill.

Does anyone have ideas how this could be done (or if it cannot) with webforms, OR if there is a better way, please?

cFusch

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Webform Calculator](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculator), I know it has checkbox support. You can set values for fields, then calculate the total amount at the end of webform for the submission.

> Provides a formula webform component for computed values, where you
>   can enter a mathematical calculation based on the other fields. E.g.,
>   create a formula field with value formkey1 * 0.1 * formkey2.

Comment: Thanks, DMAC! Webform Calculator looks like it might be the answer, but have not yet tried. I'll give it a go today and be back for a full review if it works out. Regards - cFusch